# How to set class as BaseAdapter for ListView - Android

Tags: android, class, listview, baseadapter

I have a class called CreateCommentLists, that extends BaseAdapter. How do I set the BaseAdapter class to my ListView? My current class is suppose to take comments, Usernames, and Numbers and place them into seperate textViews but this class does not work. Do I need to call the class or set the ListView to the class? I am not sure how to activate the class.

```
     class CreateCommentLists extends BaseAdapter{
    Context ctx_invitation;
    String[] listComments;
    String[] listNumbers;
    String[] listUsernames;


    public CreateCommentLists(Context ctx_invitation, String[] comments, String[] Numbers, String[] usernames)
    {
        super();
        this.ctx_invitation = ctx_invitation;
        listComments = comments;
        listNumbers = Numbers;
        listUsernames = usernames;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listComments.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listComments[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = null;
        try
        {
            String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)ctx_invitation.getSystemService(inflater);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            TextView commentView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listComment);
            TextView NumbersView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listNumber);
            TextView usernamesView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listPostedBy);


            commentView.setText(listComments[position]);
            NumbersView.setText(listNumbers[position]);
            usernamesView.setText(listUsernames[position]);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity you first create a new instance of your adapter class like this:

```
CreateCommentLists mycmlist = new CreateCommentLists(this, <your comments array>, <your Numbers array>, <your usernames array>);
```

and then you have to set it to your ListView like this:

```
lstComments = (ListView)findViewById(<lstcomments ID>);
lstComments.setAdapter(mycmlist);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: what is mycmlist? What type of variable is it?

Comment: should this go before or after the class?

Comment: Usually it goes inside the onCreate method of your activity. If the class is private it's better to be before its instantiation but it doesn't actually matter...

Answer (score 0):

Create an object "obj" of CreateCommentLists, and on list view call listView.setAdadpter(obj)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
CreateCommentLists adaper = new CreateCommentLists(context, comments, numbers, usernames);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter):
```